# SwiftUI List doesn't show Text views

Tags: list, swiftui

Playing around with SwiftUI's List view.  Can't seem to get a simple List to show some  Text entries.

Here's my SwiftUI view:

```
struct DeviceView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Text("First").foregroundColor(Color.red)
      Text("Second")
      Text("Third")
      Text("Fourth")
      Text("Fifth")
      Text("Sixth")
      Text("Seventh")
      Text("Eighth")
      Text("Ninth")
      Text("Tenth")
    }.font(.largeTitle)
  }
}
```

I'm creating the  view in  a UIKit  view controller as in:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    let swiftUIController = UIHostingController(rootView: DeviceView())

    addChild(swiftUIController)
    swiftUIController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(swiftUIController.view)

    swiftUIController.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    swiftUIController.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    swiftUIController.didMove(toParent: self)
  }
}
```

If I comment out List then the Text items show.

Why is the  List not showing the Text views?

Comment: That's not how you make a list in SwiftUI.  Use `ForEach` with an array of strings or at least use `VStack` there.

Comment: Why use the `ViewController` wrapper -- why not *just* use `UIHostingController(rootView: DeviceView())`?

Comment: Sorry  ...  don't follow. UIHostingController(rootView: DeviceView()) is exactly what  I have above. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Phantom59 at some point, you have this line of code somewhere: `ViewController()`. I'm trying to figure out why you don't just replace that with `UIHostingController(rootView: DeviceView())`. What good does the `ViewController` wrapper do?

Comment: I suppose I could ...  all  the way back in my Scene delegate. I created a small sample project to look into this which is part of a much bigger app. This is the way Xcode creates a default project. In  any case, I don't think this has anything to do  with my  original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using Playground. You need to place your SwiftUI `View` in the `UIHostingController`'s root view, as someone above commented.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(1..<11) { value in
                Text(spellout(NSNumber(value: value)).capitalized)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func spellout(_ value: NSNumber) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.string(from: value)!
    }
}

let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  but that would only work for something you can iterate thru which  is not the case for me. I used  first thru  tenth  for simplicity. But in my real I have custom Views.

Comment: You don’t have to iterate them. Use the custom views. It’s mostly the bottom view controller portion.